# How to integrate $e^{\sin x}(x \cos x - \tan x \sec x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How would on find the indefinite integral $e^{\sin x}(x \cos x - \tan x \sec x)$

Our professor gave it to us as a review question. He told us it was from an exam several years ago as extra credit, however no one answered it correctly.

I have been working on it for hours and cannot make a dent, I haven't made any progress! It isn't really important because there are no points awarded for it, however I would like to know how to do it

---

Solution based on input from Doc:

> $\int e^{\sin x}(x \cos x -\tan x \sec x)\;dx$
> $\int (e^{\sin x}\cos x)(x)\;dx - \int e^{\sin x}( \tan x \sec x)\;dx$
> $\int (e^{\sin x})'(x)\;dx - \int e^{\sin x}(\sec x)'\;dx$
> $ e^{\sin x}x-\int e^{\sin x}\;dx - (e^{\sin x}\sec x-\int \cos x e^{\sin x}\sec x\;dx)$
> $ e^{\sin x}x-\int e^{\sin x}\;dx - e^{\sin x}\sec x+\int e^{\sin x}\;dx$
> $ e^{\sin x}x - e^{\sin x}\sec x+C$
> $ e^{\sin x}(x - \sec x)+C$

Comment: I would distribute the e-power and look at the two integrals seperately. They have an "embedded" product rule in reverse...

Comment: It's a nice problem in that the "impossible" integrals cancel out when you do it by parts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it in two parts.

For $\int e^{\sin{x}}x\cos{x}dx$ use integration by parts with $u=x$ and $dv=e^{\sin{x}}\cos{x}\, dx$.

For  $\int e^{\sin{x}}\tan{x}\sec{x}dx$ use integration by parts with $u=\sin{x}$ and $dv=\tan{x}\sec{x}\, dx$

Comment: Several typos here! But nice pun.

Comment: This is what happens when you run out of coffee and all the stores are closed.  I;m _still_ not sure it's correct. Bah ..

Comment: Not quite. Have an espresso from my machine! :)

Comment: Thank you Doc. Its amazing, after doing it once, I'm surprised I didn't see what was supposed to happen from the start. Its actually much easier than I realized.